# Why do I need plugins for everything when I use requireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

I have been getting into require recently, and am happy with it. But why do I need [this 400+ line plulgin](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin) to load my handlebars templates? Handlebars templates can be stored in an html file with no plugin / conversion process involved. And if I want... I can also load them like this with jQuery/Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../templates/description.hbs',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, status, response) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile(response.responseText);
        $('#content').prepend(template(tmplData.description));
    }
});
```

I am looking for a way to load my templates.hbs files with require (or maybe not), without using a plugin. I don't like the ajax approach above, because it slows down the page load.

My templates.hbs files look something like this:

```
<div class="description">
    <h1>{{h1}}</h1>
    <p>{{p}}</p>
</div>
```

Just a string, right?

Comment: Well your code is only handling the success case (And has dependency on 20 KLOC jQuery), 95% of all code is not for success case but the error cases.

Comment: @Esailija I honestly have never experienced what you speak of. Why such a focus on the error cases, my error case is (don't display anything) or (We are missing ___, go here).

Comment: Well if you use a library and only get a white-page because some error happened in the library, would the problem be easy to find?

Comment: Oh and even for normal users, if they have a problem, do you wish that they tell you they just see a white page for any kind of error when using your application.

Comment: @Esailija this is all not really related to my question, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering the question from the title of your post ("Why do I need plugins..."), not the one in the body of it ("I am looking for a way to load my templates..."). Maybe somebody else will come along and provide an answer for that part.*

As you said, you don't **need** plugins to load the template, even if you're using RequireJS for the rest of your dependency management. However, there are a couple reasons why using the [built-in text plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text) or a dedicated Handlebars plugin (like the one you linked) can be helpful:

**1 - Handle the text dependency the same was as other dependencies**

Have a plugin lets you say that a given piece of code depends on module A, module B, and template X:

```
require(["moduleA", "moduleB", "text!templateX.html"],
    function(moduleA, moduleB, html) {
        // start working with all of it together
    }
);
```

But if you didn't use a plugin, you'd probably have another layer of callback:

```
require(["moduleA", "moduleB"],
    function(moduleA, moduleB) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../templates/templateX.html',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data, status, response) {
                // now do something
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**2 - allow a bundling/optimization phase**

RequireJS ships with the [r.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) which can bundle all the dependencies together and minify them to reduce the number of requests and their overall download size.

If you use a plugin and the require/define syntax to define all your dependencies, r.js can trace what's needed for a module and bundle it together. So in the example I used above:

```
require(["moduleA", "moduleB", "text!templateX.html"],
```

moduleA, moduleB, and templateX could be bundled together in a single file rather than having three separate runtime requests.

In the Handlebars plugin you linked, I see that some of those 400+ lines of code are dealing with the bundling/optimization phase. And as @Esailija pointed out in the comments, many of the others relate to edge cases and error conditions.